# How do I create a new function that will take in an array of numbers and add all of them?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have to create a new function that will take in an array of numbers and add all of them together. The Code below is what I have, but I'm nut sure what I'm missing.

```
var total = 0;
arr = [7, 8, 9];

function totalOfNumbers(arr){
   for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
     total += arr[i]; 
   }
   return total; 
}
console.log(totalOfNumbers);
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You might want to declare `total` inside the function and actually call the function...

Comment: You're not *calling* the function. Try `totalOfNumbers(arr)`

Comment: You are not calling the function but just printing the string function, and you better make use of Array.prototype.reduce for the this operation and call the function by passing an array as an argument to it like this
console.log(totalOfNumbers(arr))    
see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the one liner :)

```
const totalOfNumbers = arr => arr.reduce((a,v) => a + v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var total = 0;
    arr = [7, 8, 9];

    function totalOfNumbers(arr){
       for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
             total += arr[i]; 
    }
    return total; 
    }
    console.log(totalOfNumbers(arr));  //Note here calling function with arr
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call or invoke (by specifying parenthesis at the end of the function name) the function by passing the array as parameter. If you do not specify the parenthesis, instead of execution of the function, the function itself will be returned:

```js
var total = 0;
var arr = [7, 8, 9];

function totalOfNumbers(a){
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
   total += a[i]; 
  }
  return total; 
}
console.log(totalOfNumbers(arr)); // call the function by specifying parenthesis at the end of the function name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Array.prototype.reduce` method for that operation.
below is the code for the function that will make use of `reduce` method and return the sum of all values in an array

```
function totalOfNumbers(arr){
    return arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
}

/*and then call the function by passing the array that you want to    
get the sum of elements */

let arr = [7,8,9];
let sumOfArray = totalOfNumbers(arr);    
console.log(sumOfArray)
```

[Click here for further information about Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic, functional approach, that is a less terse version to add contents of an array. You probably will want to validate that all the elements are actual javascript Numbers before you try to add. You can find documentation on the reduce function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) .

```
let total = 0;
let arr = [7, 8, 9];

function totalOfNumbers(values){
   return values.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
     accumulator += value;
     return accumulator;
   }, 0);
}
console.log(totalOfNumbers(arr)); // 24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];

function add(total, num) {
  return total + num;
}
var total = numbers.reduce(getSum);
```